# Successful installed php using brew in MacBookPro (w Mojave); but not recognized on command line

Tags: php, macbook-pro, homebrew

The command `brew install php` was successful:

```
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.8: 521 files, 77.0MB
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

The system recognizes two installation fo php -- the old one and the latest one:

```
$ which -a php
/usr/local/bin/php
/usr/bin/php
```

However, the command line still "knows" only the pre-installed php:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.23 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2019 22:19:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Is this a matter of updating the `$PATH` in `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I have come to the realization that the macOS Mojave terminal instance still **contains the old state of the system**.  A new terminal instance displays the correct updated version.

Comment: TIP: After the successful installation, the terminal may be initialized using the command `$ source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oh-my-zsh try this:

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```